# What is a SubProgram ".........." in Unity shader?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

The practical part of the code is doing What?

```
//this partical >>   SubProgram "opengl " {    <<<
Keywords { "LIGHTMAP_ON" "DIRLIGHTMAP_ON" "HDR_LIGHT_PREPASS_OFF" }
Vector 0 [_Color]
SetTexture 0 [_MainTex] 2D 0
SetTexture 1 [_LightBuffer] 2D 1
SetTexture 2 [unity_Lightmap] 2D 2
"!!ARBfp1.0
PARAM c[2] = { program.local[0],
        { 8 } };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A subprogram is a way to provide specific shaders (fragment or vertex shaders) for a specific API.

So say you have the following

```cg
SubShader 
{ 
    Pass 
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        Program "vp" 
        {
            SubProgram "opengl" 
            {
                //Do something if we're rendering with OpenGL
            }
            SubProgram "gles"
            {
                //Do something if we're rendering with GLES
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then you can specifiy unique shaders given the API you're rendering with, as part of one and the same "Shader" asset.